# Reconfigure my Script in a Better Way

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I created a mousemove function to show a custom popup when the viewer places their mouse cursor over a point I plotted on a map graphic.  What I created works fine, but I was wondering could I have done it in a better way; possibly using a loop.  The elements that show inside the popup comes from a JSON file.  I created a mousemove event for each of the points plotted on the map.  The way I wrote it seems like a lot of code and I think there may be a better way.  Can someone offer me a better way of doing this concept?  Thank you in advance.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="toolTip">
    <div class="closeBtn">
        X
    </div>
    <h3>Title</h3>
    <p>Paragraph text</p>
    <div class="image">
        <a class="various fancybox.iframe fancybox-button iframe fancybox" href="page3.html" title="Leo Under the Blanket"><img alt="Image" src="graphics/leoBlanket.jpg"></a>
    </div>
</div><!--Close of Tooltip-->
<div id="container">
    <section id="focal">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div class="parent">
                <div class="panzoom">
                    <div id="content">
                        <svg height="aut0" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 1000 650" width="100%" x="0px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" y="0px">
                        <g id="map"></g>
                        <g id="points">
                            <circle class="point4" cx="169.71" cy="160.985" fill="#006838" r="7.971"></circle>
                            <circle class="point5" cx="626.957" cy="93.594" fill="#006838" r="7.971"></circle>
                            <circle class="point6" cx="476.232" cy="250.841" fill="#006838" r="7.971"></circle>
                        </g></svg>
                        <div class="point point1"><img alt="Image" src="graphics/pointIcon.png"></div>
                        <div class="point point2"><img alt="Image" src="graphics/pointIcon.png"></div>
                        <div class="point point3"><img alt="Image" src="graphics/pointIcon.png"></div>
                    </div><!--Close of Content-->
                </div><!--pan zoom-->
            </div><!--parent-->
        </div><!--Wrapper-->
    </section><button class="zoom-in">+</button> <button class="zoom-out">-</button> <input class="zoom-range" type="range"><!----> <button class="reset">1:1</button><br>
</div><!--Close of Container-->
```

My JavaScript

```
$('.point1').mousemove(function(event) {
$('.toolTip').css({
    top: event.clientY,
    left: event.clientX
}).show(); //position tooltip location
$(".toolTip h3").html(json.nodes[0].title); //add title from json file
$(".toolTip p").html(json.nodes[0].paraTxt); //add paragraph text from
json file
$(".toolTip img").attr("src", json.nodes[0].image); //add image from json
file
$(".toolTip a").attr("href", json.nodes[0].popupImg1);
});
$('.point2').mousemove(function(event) {
    $('.toolTip').css({
        top: event.clientY,
        left: event.clientX
    }).show(); //position tooltip location
    $(".toolTip h3").html(json.nodes[1].title); //add title from json file
    $(".toolTip p").html(json.nodes[1].paraTxt); //add paragraph text from 
    json file
    $(".toolTip img").attr("src", json.nodes[1].image); //add image from json 
    file
    $(".toolTip a").attr("href", json.nodes[1].popupImg2);
});
$('.point3').mousemove(function(event) {
    $('.toolTip').css({
        top: event.clientY,
        left: event.clientX
    }).show(); //position tooltip location
    $(".toolTip h3").html(json.nodes[2].title); //add title from json file
    $(".toolTip p").html(json.nodes[2].paraTxt); //add paragraph text from
    json file
    $(".toolTip img").attr("src", json.nodes[2].image); //add image from json
    file
    $(".toolTip a").attr("href", json.nodes[2].popupImg3);
});
$('.point4').mousemove(function(event) {
    $('.toolTip').css({
        top: event.clientY,
        left: event.clientX
    }).show(); //position tooltip location
    $(".toolTip h3").html(json.nodes[3].title); //add title from json file
    $(".toolTip p").html(json.nodes[3].paraTxt); //add paragraph text from
    json file
    $(".toolTip img").attr("src", json.nodes[3].image); //add image from json
    file
    $(".toolTip a").attr("href", json.nodes[3].popupImg4);
});
$('.point5').mousemove(function(event) {
    $('.toolTip').css({
        top: event.clientY,
        left: event.clientX
    }).show(); //position tooltip location
    $(".toolTip h3").html(json.nodes[4].title); //add title from json file
    $(".toolTip p").html(json.nodes[4].paraTxt); //add paragraph text from  
    json file
    $(".toolTip img").attr("src", json.nodes[4].image); //add image from 
    json file
    $(".toolTip a").attr("href", json.nodes[4].popupImg5);
});
$('.point6').mousemove(function(event) {
    $('.toolTip').css({
        top: event.clientY,
        left: event.clientX
    }).show(); //position tooltip location
    $(".toolTip h3").html(json.nodes[5].title); //add title from json file
    $(".toolTip p").html(json.nodes[5].paraTxt); //add paragraph text from 
    json file
    $(".toolTip img").attr("src", json.nodes[5].image); //add image from json
    file
    $(".toolTip a").attr("href", json.nodes[5].popupImg6);
});
```

My JSON

```
var json = {
"nodes": [{
"id": 0,
"button": $('.point1'),
"popupImg": "page3.html",
"image": "graphics/leoBlanket.jpg",
"title": "point 0 ",
"paraTxt": "Snug as a bug in the blanket"
  },
{
"id": 1,
"button": $('.point2'),
"popupImg": "page3.html",
"image": "graphics/image1.jpg",
 "title": "point 1",
"paraTxt": "You got to see this view!"
}, 
{
"id": 2,
"button": $('.point3'),
"popupImg": "page3.html",
"image": "graphics/image2.jpg",
"title": "point 2",
"paraTxt": "Love the great view"
 }, 
{
"id": 3,
"button": $('.point4'),
"popupImg": "page3.html",
"image": "graphics/myMap.png",
"title": "point 3",
"paraTxt": "Love the great view"
}, 
{
"id": 4,
"button": $('.point5'),
"popupImg": "page3.html",
"image": "graphics/myMap.png",
"title": "point 4   ",
"paraTxt": "Love the great view"
}, 
{
"id": 5,
"button": $('.point6'),
"popupImg": "page3.html",
"image": "graphics/myMap.png",
"title": "point 5",
"paraTxt": "Love the great view"
}]
};
```

Loop Concept offered and modified to load JSON data -- not working for all points.  If I remove the if statement it will only display the JSON data of the last JSON element.

```
for (var i = 0; i < json.nodes.length; i++) {
if (i == 3) {
    json.nodes[i].button.mousemove(function(event) {
        $('.toolTip').css({
            top: event.clientY,
            left: event.clientX
        }).show(); //position tooltip location
        $(".toolTip h3").html(json.nodes[i].title); //add title from json file
        $(".toolTip p").html(json.nodes[i].paraTxt); //add paragraph text from json file
        $(".toolTip img").attr("src", json.nodes[i].image); //add image from json file
        $(".toolTip a").attr("href", json.nodes[i].popupImg[i + 1]);
    });
    break;
   }
}
```

Comment: `but I was wondering could I have done it in a better way` - I'd recommend code indentation for a start - if you have trouble with that, paste your code into jsfiddle.net and hit the `Tidy` button

Comment: I indented the code and I included Jaromanda X loop concept - modified - to display the correct data from the JSON file.  The modified concept show the last data in the JSON or using the if statement shows only that elements data.  In this case the date for object 4.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `for` loop with `let` should get you the results you want.

```
var points = 6;
for (let i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    $('.point' + (i + 1)).mousemove(function(event) {
    $('.toolTip').css({top: event.clientY, left: event.clientX}).show();//position tooltip location
    $(".toolTip h3").html(json.nodes[i].title);//add title from json file
    $(".toolTip p").html(json.nodes[i].paraTxt);//add paragraph text from json file
    $(".toolTip img").attr("src", json.nodes[i].image);//add image from json file
    $(".toolTip a").attr("href", json.nodes[i].popupImg[i + 1]);
    });
}
```

At the urging of Jaromanda X, I must inform you that IE does not like `let`, so for maximum compatibility with those running antiquated browsers use an IIFE:

```
var points = 6;
for (var i = 0; i < points; i++) {
    !function(i) {
        $('.point' + (i + 1)).mousemove(function(event) {
        $('.toolTip').css({top: event.clientY, left: event.clientX}).show();//position tooltip location
        $(".toolTip h3").html(json.nodes[i].title);//add title from json file
        $(".toolTip p").html(json.nodes[i].paraTxt);//add paragraph text from json file
        $(".toolTip img").attr("src", json.nodes[i].image);//add image from json file
        $(".toolTip a").attr("href", json.nodes[i].popupImg[i + 1]);
        });
    }(i);
}
```

Yeah, it's ugly. But it works.

Comment: you could add a note that `let` only works in modern browsers, so IE won't work with this code :p

Comment: I've been on Linux for the last several years. Is that a limitation in all IE versions?

Comment: IE yes, Edge no

Comment: Thanks  Jaromanda X...first sorry for the format issue.  Placing my script in the question area was a bear :).  On the script you modified/provided is great, the popup shows when I place the mouse cursor on the different points; but the information in the popup is not being updated from the JSON object when I'm on that point.  How do I make each particular point show it's unique data from the JSON file? Thanks in advance -- Tony T

Comment: This is on the path of what requesting but not quite.  The proper information load but for the 4th object in the JSON file.  The if statement changes the i value and the break code stops the loop.  How to include this concept for the rest of the JSON object to load.

Comment: for (var i = 0; i < json.nodes.length; i++ ){
 if ( i == 3){ 
   json.nodes[i].button.mousemove(function(event) {
        $('.toolTip').css({top: event.clientY, left: event.clientX}).show();//position tooltip location
        $(".toolTip h3").html(json.nodes[i].title);//add title from json file
        $(".toolTip p").html(json.nodes[i].paraTxt);//add paragraph text from json file
        $(".toolTip img").attr("src", json.nodes[i].image);//add image from json file
        $(".toolTip a").attr("href", json.nodes[i].popupImg[i + 1]);
        });

  break;
 }
}

Comment: When using a for loop the value of "i" will chance after each iteration. That's why you need the `let` or IIFE (`!function(i)`) to preserve the value. Also your comment code is lacking the `i + 1` in the first line after the `if` statement. --- Also fixed my C&P induced typo in the IIFE variable name. Sorry about that.

Comment: I was a bit confused by your last comment, but it appears you are asking why your loop doesn't continue after you `break` it. Simple answer: **Don't do that!** There is no reason to break the loop at that point.